# Why is the chag not Goralot?

Tags: names, purim

The Megillah says the chag is named after the Persian "Pur" (Esther 9:26 - language identified in Targum Sheini to 3:7). Why is it not named "Goralot," in Hebrew, like the other chagim?

Comment: Tu Bishvat isn't Hebrew and neither is Tu BeAv.

Comment: Frankly Shushan Purim isn't really Hebrew too but [proto-] Yiddish. In Hebrew it'd be Purim Shushan (or maybe Purei Shushan)

Comment: @DoubleAA Given that the names of the months have become commonplace in Hebrew, Tu Beshvat would be the correct way to say it. (Besides, those names never appear in Shas, nor are they identified as holidays. Their significances are, but not as an established holiday.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. Zaddoq Hakohen of Lublin writes as follows in Resissei Layla (58):

> ענין קריאת ימי הפורים על שם הפור והוא הגורל אלא שבלשון פרסי נקרא פור והוצרך הכתוב לזכור שמו בלשון פרסי ולתרגמו ללשון הקודש **לפי שהימים קראו כשם הפרסי שכפי הנראה היה נקרא כן בפי בני ישראל אז**. **וזה טעם על כן קראו** וגו' ולא פירש מי **דרצה לומר המון בני ישראל קראו כן** שכך הוא מפורסם שם ימים הללו אז.

That is, the holiday Purim is known as a Persian word, since it was named by the populace who spoke Persian.

It should be noted that other holidays' names were generally assigned by God; not popular preference of Persian populace.

Answer (score 0):

mefirshimm on posuk in megillah....
“הפיל פור הוא הגורל”
that it was not a ordinary gorulll
hence the words purr ,it is a gorulll”

one reason given....
is that the word purr is implying a complex and rare
way to figure out great chances of 
כוח הטומאה and also this purr used magic etc
therefore gorul is never used in this manner
so gorul is not used

this maybe answers your question!
since the chag is named after this special 
kind of gorulll that was accurate and bad
we need to say purim PURR and not goralot
which would imply a not so serious of a threat
and as the גר״א says we are focused on the 
threat even in the end because that was the 
Ness just upside down

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a פור and a גורל, though? Can you quote this Maharal directly?

Comment: the maharal is in OHR CHODOSH

Comment: I see you're new here and might not understand quite how MY works, since it's different from other sites you might be used to. Why don't you take a look at our [tour] when you get a chance? We prefer answers which are well-written, which directly and completely address the question at hand, and, where relevant, which quotes all relevant sources in the body of the answer itself. Would you be able to [edit] your answer accordingly when you can?

Comment: The difference can be many things for example if i take two papers and write 2 numbers and draw them from lot it’s a GORUL       But if i would use Special Blackmagic with many different tools of Tumah that were included in Hamans  lot it would be called a PUR

Comment: Please [edit] all relevant information into the post itself.